# Как сохранить временные данные глобально? WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Я использую WordPress и мне требуеться сохранить данные куда-нибудь что бы извлекать их в нескольких разных скриптах (т.е. человек выполнил несколько переходов по разным страницам).
Если можно - приведите пожалуйста пример как сохранить данные в какой либо структуре и извлечь их. Спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант: сессии используйте https://www.google.ru/search?q=wordpress%2Bsession

Comment: Не нравятся сессии - заведите таблицу для таких переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WordPress стартовать и уничтожать сессию нужно во время события init. Такой подход обеспечивает возможность ее использования в теме и плагинах, а также в коде ajax. Добавьте такой код в functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_start_session', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'my_end_session' );
add_action( 'wp_login', 'my_end_session' );

function my_start_session() {
    if ( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function my_end_session() {
    session_destroy();
}
```

В первой строке указан приоритет = 1 для того, чтобы сессия была запущена ранее всех остальных хуков, выполняющихся по событию init.

Строки 2 и 3 добавляют хуки,уничтожающие сессию, если пользователь вышел из учётной записи WordPress или пытается войти в учётную запись (возможно, под новым именем).

Проверка `if ( ! session_id() )` нужна для того, чтобы php не выдал предупреждение E_NOTICE. Но и без этой проверки код будет работать, потому что `session_start()` создаёт новую сессию или возобновляет текущую.

Использование.

Записать данные в сессию можно таким образом:

```
$_SESSION['my_key'] = "Информация о пользователе, которую нужно сохранить";
```

А извлечь - таким образом:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['my_key'] ) ) {
    $value = $_SESSION['my_key'];
} else {
    $value = '';
}
```

Comment: Это действительно тот ответ который нужен был мне. Спасибо большое!